# In how many ways can 11 # signs and 8 * signs be arranged in a row so that no two * signs come together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Could I get a hint for this problem? I don't want the answer, but maybe a way to think of it in the right direction. So far I know there are 19 characters total, and we cannot have two asterisks (*) next to each other. So one example would be:

```
#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*###
```

Another example would be:

```
####*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*
```

So what I know is that there are three extra pound (#) symbols that can be anywhere else, where order does not matter for it. Because once we get the last asterisk, those remaining pound symbols can go anywhere because it doesn't matter since no asterisk will succeed another.

I'm out of thoughts, anything would help. Thanks

Comment: Are there supposed to be $8$ *s?  It doesn't say so in the title.

Comment: Yes sorry, 8 asterisks, not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 2):

Put the $8$ *s in a row.  We have to put $7$ #s between them.  Now there are $9$ places to put the remaining $4$ asterisks.  Use stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of ways you can divide $11$ elements into $8$ groups (a group can't be empty and order is important), then place an asterisk between every two groups.

Comment: Asterix is a fictional character whose name was meant to be humorous for its mis-spelling of *asterisk*. I hope you don't mind me editing him out!

Comment: @timtfj but why can't I put an Asterix between every two Roman legions?

Comment: Actually that sounds highly practical! Except it would pretty quickly turn into a line of Asterixes and no longer be a valid solution . . .